# XSL: Document is empty

Tags: xml, xslt, document

When I try to view my xml tree I get this error

"This page contains the following errors:

error on line 5 at column 1: Document is empty"

here is my xsl to line 5:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="books.xsl"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="books">
    <html>
      <head>
```

Link: http://infd.birdnest.org/~grangere2/CSCI441/books.xsl

Comment: Why do you have an xsl stylesheet linked into your XSL file?

Comment: the href="books.xsl" isn't there in his link ...

Answer (score 0):

Are you applying your xsl to your xml correctly ? For example, using a random XML document I found that'll work with your xsl:

saxon http://tinyurl.com/a5bcf42 http://infd.birdnest.org/~grangere2/CSCI441/books.xsl

or

xsltproc http://infd.birdnest.org/~grangere2/CSCI441/books.xsl http://tinyurl.com/a5bcf42